# angularjs if object is empty return a string in HTML class

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my html file, I have

```
<td data-ng-repeat="definition in visibleColumnDefinition"
    ng-style="{'width': definition.width}" class="table-ajax-col-{{definition.columnHeaderDisplayName}}">
```

, where columnHeaderDisplayName may return empty. I would like to have a if condition to check whether columnHeaderDisplayName is empty or not and return a string.

```
!columnHeaderDisplay?$index : columnHeaderDisplay
```

What is the syntax to do that if logic in angularjs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did this not work?

```
<td data-ng-repeat="definition in visibleColumnDefinition track by $index"
    ng-style="{'width': definition.width}" class="table-ajax-col-{{definition.columnHeaderDisplayName ? definition.columnHeaderDisplayName : $index}}">
```

You looked about there

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend separating this sticky logic into a safe, loving, controller where it can live, be cared for, and maintained with ease:

```
$scope.fetchClassNameForColumnHeaderBasedOnHeaderDisplayName = fetchClassNameForColumnHeaderBasedOnHeaderDisplayNameFn(displayNameString, indexVariable) {
  if (displayNameString && displayNameString !== '') {
    return 'table-ajax-col-' + displayNameString;
  } else {
    return 'table-ajax-col-' + indexVariable
  }
}
```

Then you can simply bind this to an ng-class as an expression passing in your `displayString` and `$index` variable.

```
<td data-ng-repeat="definition in visibleColumnDefinition"
    ng-style="{'width': definition.width}" 
    ng-class="fetchClassNameForColumnHeaderBasedOnHeaderDisplayName(definition.columnHeaderDisplayName, $index)"
>
```